# How to create multiple excel files in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying the below code which is intended to create two excel files at @AfterClass.

```
   String strTablePathR2 = "--path--";

    String filename2 = strTablePathR2 + "Results-1"
            + Functions.getDateAndHour() + ".xls";

   HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
   HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

   HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((int)0);
   row.createCell((int)0).setCellValue("HelloWorld");

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename2);
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.flush();
   fileOut.close();
   //----------------------------------------------

   String filename3 = strTablePathR2 + "Results-2"
            + CommonFunctions.getDateAndHour() + ".xls";

   HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
   HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet1");

   HSSFRow row1 = sheet1.createRow((int)0);
   row1.createCell((int)0).setCellValue("HelloWorld1");

   FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream(filename3);
   wb.write(fileOut2);
   fileOut2.flush();
   fileOut2.close();
```

The issue is that two similar excel sheets are created with the same content of the first excel sheet. So according to this simple example, two excel sheets will be created namely, Results-1 & Results-2 with the cell value, "HelloWorld". Ideally in the second excel the cell value should be "HelloWorld1". Please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a typing mistake:

```
String filename3 = strTablePathR2 + "Results-2"
        + CommonFunctions.getDateAndHour() + ".xls";

HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet1 = **wb1**.createSheet("new sheet1");

HSSFRow row1 = sheet1.createRow((int)0);
row1.createCell((int)0).setCellValue("HelloWorld1");

FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream(filename3);
**wb1**.write(fileOut2);
fileOut2.flush();
fileOut2.close();
```

Comment: Ohh sorry my bad..I changed the code before posting. The issue remains the same, even if I try with wb1